# Iteration in password-based Key derivation function 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, salt, pbkdf2, hashlib

so I am currently learning Python and am learning about encryption methods in that language. There I found the function pbkdf2_hmac(hash_name, password, salt, iterations, dklen=None) from the hashlib library.

However, the parameter "iterations" does not work as I expect it to. As the following simple code shows, when i try to call the function twice with one iteration, I get a different answer then when I call it once with two iterations. Since hashing functions are deterministic, both methods should yield the same result.

```
import hashlib
a=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256",b"hallo",b"salt",1)
b=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256",a,b"salt",1)
c=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256",b"hallo",b"salt",2)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd iterations of [PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2) isn't just PBKDF2(the first iteration).

A simplified explanation is:

- 1 iteration: `HMAC(password, salt || 00000001)`
- 2 iterations: `HMAC(password, HMAC(password, salt || 00000001))`
- PBKDF2(PBKDF2): `HMAC(HMAC(password, salt || 00000001), salt || 00000001)`

Note that the "2 iterations" and "PBKDF2(PBKDF2)" versions use different HMAC keys for the second computation, which is why they give different results.

As far as "hashing functions are deterministic": They are.  If you call them with the same inputs they give the same outputs.  You gave them different inputs, due to misunderstanding how the underlying algorithm works.